# MySQL, how to JOIN many records to one

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to get information from a wordpress database; the data I need is spread between 3 tables:

- wp_em_events
- wp_em_locations
- wp_postmeta

A simplified diagram:

```
wp_em_events
+-----+--------+-----+
| id  | loc_id | a   |
+-----+--------+-----+
|   1 | 3      | foo |
|   2 | 4      | bar |
+-----+--------+-----+

wp_em_locations
+--------+----+
| loc_id | b  |
+--------+----+
|    3   | x  |
|    4   | y  |
+--------+----+

wp_postmeta
+-------+------+------+
|post_id| key  |value |
+-------+------+------+
|    1  | name | dave |
|    1  | age  | 14   |
|    2  | name | rob  |
|    2  | age  | 20   |
+-------+------+------+

$querystr = "
    SELECT *
    FROM wp_em_events
    LEFT JOIN wp_em_locations ON wp_em_events.loc_id = wp_em_locations.loc_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_em_events.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
    WHERE wp_em_events.id = 1
    GROUP BY wp_em_events.location_id, wp_em_events.id
";
```

**This would return:**

```
+-----+--------+-----+----+-----+-------+
| id  | loc_id | a   |  b | key | value |
+-----+--------+-----+----+-----+-------+
|   1 | 3      | foo |  x | age |  20   |
+-----+--------+-----+----+-----+-------+
```

Where my GROUP BY has destroyed the name->dave **I would like to receive:**

```
+-----+--------+-----+----+-----+-----+
| id  | loc_id | a   |  b | name| age |
+-----+--------+-----+----+-----+-----+
|   1 | 3      | foo |  x | dave|  14 |
+-----+--------+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

I need to capture ALL of the meta records, and associate them somehow with the parent record, preferably as the key->value that they are.

Comment: wp_em_events.post_id doesn't exist in your sample data

Comment: Thanks, this was only hypothetical since the actual table details are much messier. I'm just looking for any way to preserve all the "meta" records and associate them with the "events" without doing recursive queries.

Comment: I don't think you need recursive queries. Just two. Similar to @Darfs answer except the MySQL version (which isn't as nice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could do this..

```
SELECT e.id, 
       e.loc_id, 
       e.a, 
       l.b, 
       p_name.Value `Name`, 
       p_age.Value  Age 
FROM   wp_em_events e 
       INNER JOIN wp_em_locations l 
         ON e.loc_id = l.loc_id 
       INNER JOIN wp_postmeta p_name 
         ON e.id = p_name.Post_id 

       INNER JOIN wp_postmeta p_age 
         ON e.id = p_age.Post_id 

WHERE  e.id = 1 
            AND p_name.`key` = 'name' 
            AND p_age.`key` = 'age'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a7ac/21)

But you'd need to construct the query dynamically. Specifically the column names and aliases and the WHERE clause

Comment: I can't pretend to be able to dissect this just yet without googling the components (at work), but it looks like the output is what I was looking for and the structure more what I was expecting. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Do a dynamic pivot table. here You got a example that I've been using for one of my projects. It is not directly connected with Your case but You will get the point.

```
create table testowy_pivot
            (
             name varchar(255),
             color varchar(255),
             quantity int
            )

insert into testowy_pivot (name, color, quantity) values ('road frames','black',null)
insert into testowy_pivot (name, color, quantity) values ('road frames','red',null)
insert into testowy_pivot (name, color, quantity) values ('helmets','red',288)
insert into testowy_pivot (name, color, quantity) values ('helmets','black',324)
insert into testowy_pivot (name, color, quantity) values ('helmets','blue',216)
insert into testowy_pivot (name, color, quantity) values ('socks','white',180)
insert into testowy_pivot (name, color, quantity) values ('socks','white',216)


DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT
@columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(color as varchar) + ']','[' + cast(color as varchar)+ ']')
FROM testowy_pivot
GROUP BY color


DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)

SET @query = '
           SELECT *
                     FROM testowy_pivot
                               PIVOT
                                  (
                           sum(quantity) --sum, max, etc.
                               FOR [color]
                               IN (' + @columns + ')
                                  )
                     AS p'

EXECUTE(@query)

select * from testowy_pivot
```

regards, 
m.

Comment: If SQL Server yes. MySQL not so much

Comment: true - this is sql but pivot in mysql is also possible http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot. It seems like an awfully complex solution for what I imagined would be a pretty standard problem in record keeping.